# Navigate to "next" and "previous" Item

Tags: ember.js

I hava a slightly complicated data model. 
The main model is a betround in which several people can bet on sport events. Within every betround everyone bets on multiple games (maybe 1 game day). Now I want to build a stats screen which shows all bets grouped by games. But I only want to show the bets for one game at a time and then via next / previous buttons navigate to the bets for the next game within the betround.

I am currently trying to achieve this with queryparams. ( [Filter with query parameter based on related model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512506/filter-with-query-parameter-based-on-related-model)).

But the next question will be how to navigate to the next game. Maybe query params are not even the best approach, maybe I should have went for a grouping or something. Anyways, I have no idea how to navigate / paginate around within one betround. My statsscreen might be active on game 30. And within my Betround there are only game 28, 30 and 31. I would need to create a Array only with the games, sort them by date and then locate the "current" game. And then determine the next and previous within my collection.

How could I tackle this kind of thing?